# Securing REST API with Security REST plugin

Tags: api, security, rest, grails, plugins

I'm building a decision support tool in GRAILS for the room scheduling at my highschool. I'm using Spring Security and I want to secure the REST api. I've  found very little information on the proper way to do this. However I've been looking to the [Spring Security REST plugin](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/introduction.html)

The documentation is not very clear to me, does anyone have a working example/tutorial using this plugin?

Suggestions on how to implement this would be great.

Comment: Have you gone through the [sequence diagram](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/introduction.html)? Did you go through the whole documentation word by word? have you tried anything?

Comment: The only documentation I found was [here](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/). The main problem is that I don't know what steps I have to do by hand to make the plugin work and which steps are automatically performed by the plugin. @dmahapatro

Comment: You just need the GORM related configurations if you are using GORM storage right now and are using 1.3.0.RC version.

Comment: Do you have a code base for a running app which I can look at and notify where changes are required? otherwise if you wait till EOD today I would be able to forward you the sample app.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to your sample app.

Comment: Sample app in [github](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-spring-security-rest-sample) as promised. :)

Comment: I got my example working , but i had to disable this

//grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true

otherwise jQuery wouldn't send the parameters correctly. Any idea what the cause of this is?

Comment: by default it POSTs username and password as query parameters. I am submitting the request as a request JSON body, hence using that credential. Normally POST should have a request body instead of parameters.

Comment: On a side note, totally unrelated to question. Have you seen this? http://groovy.codehaus.org/GSoC+2014 u might be a interested.

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial http://nimavat.me/blog/secure-rest-api-with-springsecurity-rest-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just reading out the sequence diagram loud for you. I am working on a sample app using this plugin and (AngularJS in client side) and will be releasing soon (probably tonight).

Here are the steps:

- Client requests for a REST resource using any HTTP method.
- Server responds to client's request with a 401 (unauthorized).
- Client (on receiving a 401) redirects user to login page to provide username and password. (Remember Spring Security Core plugin)
- User provides username and password. (means, the client should issue a POST request hitting /api/login provided by spring security REST plugin with a request body/request param with user details)
- Server on receiving user info does 4 tasks:

  - Validate user.
  - Generate a token (provided by the Spring Security REST plugin by default).
  - Store the token (either in memcahe or GORM specified domain classes).
  - Return back the token to callee (client).
- On receiving the generated token from the server, client stores it in any local storage and uses for further API calls for that particular user.
- Every time an API is hit for any resource, the token is passed in the header as `X-Auth-Token` (default) instead of passing `Basic Auth` every time.

Therefore, you end up with a token based validation for the REST Endpoints. 
Go through plugin's [FAQ](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/faq.html) for more answers.

Author will be releasing the latest version of plugin (1.3.0) very soon and you would find some updates in the documentation.

I have just touched the basic functionality of this plugin right now, but it has the flexibility to handle more than just generating token. Example, [delegating auth to OAuth providers](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/oauth.html). I will update the link to the aforementioned sample app in this answer as soon as I push it to github.

**UPDATE:**
[Sample App](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-spring-security-rest-sample)